# MongoDB explain() cursor field

Tags: mongodb

I am starting to investigate into MongoDB and was looking into query stats and optimising through indexes. The examples I am reading use the explain function but their output is different from mine.

Theirs looks like:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor username_1",
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "n" : 1,
    "millis" : 3,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "username" : [
            [
                "user101",
                "user101"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

while mine:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "yodemo2-dev.indexTest",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [ ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [ ]
            },
            "direction" : "forward"
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "Andromache.local",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.0.3",
        "gitVersion" : "nogitversion"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I've used the verbose version as well although it was not the case in the example, to no avail.

How can I get their results?

Comment: which version of MongoDB are you using? And also can you add all queries you have done (including supplied arguments to `explain()`) to the post?

Comment: I am running version 3.0.3. My query is a 'db.indexTest.find().explain()'. indexTest is a collection with a few thousand very simple documents, generated through a simple for loop, with the index of the loop being concatenated to their name parameter.

Comment: So what is the output when you run the explain with verbose option like `explain("allPlansExecution")` as well as `explain("executionStats")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

explain() output changed in 3.0.  "Theirs" is <3.0 output.

Comment: Great. How can I get this information however? I seem to need the "cursor" key.

Comment: If you call explain(true)  (a.k.a. verbose) you will get essentially all the information from <3.0.   What do you need the cursor field for?